# iptables and routing mechanics

Tags: networking, iptables

At what stages of handling a data packet does the linux kernel apply the different iptables chains and routing? I am looking for a schematic overview of the process.

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/iptables-manual.html) article with this [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) schematic that is quite explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD are three separate chains. A packet will only hit one of these three.

The order for forwarded packets is: PREROUTING -> [routing] -> FORWARD -> POSTROUTING.

The netfilter doco is pretty good on this topic: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: If a packet only ever hits one of the three filter chains, shouldn't the order for forwarded packets be: PREROUTING -> [routing] -> FORWARD -> POSTROUTING (ackording to the doc you linked)?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I've updated my answer. Not sure where my head was!